# POJO with calendar

Tags: android, android-calendar

I have a model where i want to same android calendar; My code looks like :

model :

```
public class NewSchedule 
{
  Calendar mCalendar;
  String mDay;


public NewSchedule(Calendar nCalendar)
{
 this.mCalendar = nCalendar;
 this.mDay = String.valueOf(nCalendarDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); 
 }
}



List<NewSchedule> mNewSchedule = new ArrayList()<>;
Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
for (int i=0; i<10;i++)      {
   mNewSchedule.add(new NewSchedule(mCalendar);
   mCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
}
```

The problem if at the end if loop my model all the values stored in mCalendar variable refletcs the last value; But the mDay variable store the coresponded value from the for loop;

ex :

if my for loop sends the next ten days from now, my mCalendar variable will print at the end 10 values from the last mCalendar value but the mDay variable will show the correct values (05,06,07...)

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

you are creating the instance of calendar before the loop. So the value of `mCalender` remains same.

Change it to:

`for (int i=0; i<10;i++) { 
mNewSchedule.add(new NewSchedule(Calendar.getInstance().add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1));
}`

Comment: i'm not sure it will work becaus mDay variable shows the correct values and if i make like your way i will always have only the next day of the current day.

Comment: you were adding the same instance to the NewSchedule. So all the newSchedule were pointing to the same mCalendar instance and change in any one will be reflected in all of them. So only the last value was seen in the complete list

Comment: yes!  and only if i extract the day number in any new insert.... works. But i want to same all the instance of Calendar... for futer other information extration. Until now i found that i can save it in a long variable with mCalendar.getTimetoMills()... and them create the calendar instance using this;